# GCM: Should I start InstanceIDListenerService by myself in Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

From the official [website](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) , I download an example of GCM, there is a service that can detect the refresh Token, the code is as follows:

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDLS";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
 * InstanceID provider.
 */
// [START refresh_token]
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
// [END refresh_token]
}
```

My question is : Should I write  a code to start the service by myself?
just like:

```
startService(new Intent(getActivity(), MyInstanceIDListenerService.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This service is started when necessary by Google Play services. Just be sure to define the service in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Also if you are just starting out you may want to have a look at the easier to implement [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).

See a sample of FCM [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging).

Comment: Thanks ， can you give me more detail, Google Play services, how to start it(Which class start it)?  Just like"GcmListenerService" was started by "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" , can you tell me how was InstanceIDListenerService started?

Comment: Google Play services is always running. InstanceIDListenerService would be started by GcmReceiver as well.

Comment: what if sendRegistrationIdTo server call failed ?